# Telerik Silverlight GridView Sublist

Tags: silverlight, gridview, telerik, radgridview

Im not exactly well versed with Telerik or even silverlight but I do have a question about something. Lets say I have a grid view for uploading images for an account. So I log in, upload the images and they are stored in an object with the Account name they were uploaded for, then the ItemSource is binded to this object and the Account they were uploaded for is displayed.

So lets say my name is John and I manage 3 accounts, Bears, Tigers, and Wolves, and Im uploading images for 2 of them. I log in, select Bears and upload 3 images. They are sent to the database with their file information and stored in the database (like file name, type, uploading user, time and date etc, account its for etc), and the object has the list of images uploaded along with the account name Bears; then the gridView.ItemSource is set to the object and it populates one row in the gridView and it just says "Bears". Then I repeat the process but this time for Wolves, and when the gridView is binded the second time, there are 2 records in the gridView. "Bears" and "Wolves". Next to each object is a little + sign, would it be possible so when the user clicks the + sign, to display the images uploaded for the account?

Im not exactly sure how templates work with silverlight or telerik controls but is this possible so if i uploaded files for Bears called, bears1.jpg, bears2.jpg and bears3.jpg, and i click on the + sign by the "Bears" item in the gridview, it drops down and shows the 3 file names?

More info just in case

I think basically what I want to do is create a simple GridView so when the images are uploaded, in the background I have an object called "Upload" with the account it was uploaded for "Bears/Wolves....etc", who uploaded it, and a list (ObservableCollection) or the image objects (which has the file name, image type, size, upload date etc). So when I am done uploaded, then I set the gridview.ItemSource = uploadObject, and I want the sub row/hierarchical/child gridView rows to be generated off of the uploadObject.Images list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/gridview-basic-hierarchies.html and use Binding for items.

Your items and their sub-items must be implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.

Beside this you can use EntitySets , ObservableCollections for collection change triggering because they implemented ICollcectionChanged interface.

If you do things like this you will not interest in UI. You can change your model items which bound to UI. Then you will see that your UI Updated authomatically.

Hope Helps

Comment: Here is some more maybe helpful info

I think basically what I want to do is create a simple GridView so when the images are uploaded, in the background I have an object called "Upload" with the account it was uploaded for "Bears/Wolves....etc", who uploaded it, and a list (ObservableCollection) or the image objects (which has the file name, image type, size, upload date etc). So when I am done uploaded, then I set the gridview.ItemSource = uploadObject, and I want the sub row/hierarchical/child gridView rows to be generated off of the uploadObject.Images list. How can I do that?

Comment: Its ok, I used RadUploader before,if you want to be notified the upload operation finished.RadUpload supply events.Your solution in "gridview.ItemSource = uploadObject" each upload object's one member must be bound to sub-grid.One of subgrid's column definition's template can display your image attached uploadObject members.AFAIK there are samples on silverlight demos.